# R- XML within data frame instances

Tags: r, xml, list, dataframe

I have a data frame that has columns contains `id`, `xml` and some other data which looks like this:

[image]

I am wondering the best way to extract the data from the `xml` into new columns:

```
<doc>
<person>
<condition>
</condition>
<condition>
</condition>
</person>
</doc>
```

I have been using the function `genXtract` from the `qdap` package but this creates them as a list as I cam have multiples.

How can I convert the `xml` when it contains multiple of the same namespaces? or how can I convert a list inside of a data frame into a string?

Comment: It depends on what you want to extract and the structure of the data. You didn't provide any example data.

Comment: The best way to extract data is with an XML parser and XPath expressions.